# If cell value changes, copy value to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I created a project management template where I update the project's status on a regular basis.

I want as soon as the cell value of one cell changes, the exact value will be copied to a cell on another worksheet.

If the cell value of the original cell is changed again (due to further project updates), I want the value to be copied again but below the previous copy, and so on.

As I would like to solve the problem on my own, I would be happy if you could give me some hints on how to proceed or where to look.

Comment: Is there an add-on to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change()` event. For example, if the cell you're changing is `A1`, test to see if the `Target` cell matches. If so, determine the last used row on your destination sheet (`Sheet2`, below) and then assign the value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then

        ' Get the last row on our destination sheet (using Sheet2, col A here)...
        Dim intLastRow As Long
        intLastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        ' Add our value to the next row...
        Sheet2.Cells(intLastRow + 1, "A") = Target.Value

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the code above but get a "object required" error for the row intLastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Do you have a Sheet2?

Comment: sorry my mistake.. I just had to change the declaration "sheet2" to the german declaration used my excel version which is "Tabelle2".. its now running perfectly.. Thanks a lot