# How do you copy cell data when value changes?

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to copy cell data from sheet 1 I.E. cell a5 to another sheet that is referenced on sheet 1 in cell at. In essence, cell a5 on sheet 1 has the text "rdw" in it and that needs to be copied to sheet 2 to a location referenced in sheet 1 in cell a1 (I.e. $C$4). The cell reference in cell a1 at on sheet 1 is changeable so that means the data in a5 on sheet 1 can be copied to different locations. No formulas can be entered on sheet 2 that is why it needs  to be vba code. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If cell value changes, copy value to another worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973331/if-cell-value-changes-copy-value-to-another-worksheet). This has been covered so many times on [so], please search before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding VBA code in the worksheet change function of sheet1 (Menu-> Developer -> Visual Basic -> Sheet1). You may want to add code to make sure sheet2 is present, the value in Sheet1-A1 is a valid input (B1 in this case), etc.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value).Value = Target.Value
    End If
End Sub
```